# .on click jquery deleting comments

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

```
    <div class="btn-group pull-right comment-icons">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs delete-comment"  title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><!---->
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
```

I'm trying to implement a .on click event handler for deleting new elements which enter the dom. However, the code I have posted only works for current elements and not future elements. Would someone be able to explain what the issue in the code may be. It would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".comment-icons").on("click", ".delete-comment",

function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var author_id = parseInt($this.parents(".message").data("author"));
    var comment_id = parseInt($this.parents(".message").data("comment"));

    $(".modal-footer").off("click").on("click", ".confirm-delete", //want to add or on press enter

        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $.post("/comment/deletecomment",
                {comment_id: comment_id, author_id: author_id},
                function (response) {

                    var id = response.comment_id;
                    console.log(response);

                    var comment_count_holder = $this.parents(".comments-area").find(".comment-count");
                    if(comment_count_holder.length != 0){

                        var comment_count = comment_count_holder.data("commentcount");

                        comment_count = comment_count - 1;
                        comment_count_holder.data("commentcount", comment_count);
                        comment_count = comment_count_holder.data("commentcount");
                        if(comment_count >3){
                            comment_count_holder.html("View all "+comment_count+" comments")
                        }
                        else{
                            comment_count_holder.hide();
                        }
                    }

                    $("div#"+id).remove();

                },
                'json'
            );

        });

});
```

Comment: Try `$("body").on("click", ".comment-icons .delete-comment", ...)`

Comment: @Charlie
I think that worked. Could you enlighten me on why my way probably wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, attaching the `click` listener to the `body` element should work:

```
$("body").on("click", ".comment-icons .delete-comment", ...)
```

[Per the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

Consequently, new `.comment-icons` elements don't have the event attached to them. Instead, by attaching the event to the `body` element then later specifying `.comment-icons`, you are using a delegated event:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

At least that's why I think it's occurring. It also have to do with something else, but I'm not entirely sure.